# UITableView, UISearchController and MJRefresh, vertical scroll indicator flash from left to right

Tags: ios, uitableview, graphics, uisearchcontroller

Background: iOS8.x, iOS9.x, iOS10.x(before 11.0)
Using UISearchController's searchBar as the tableHeaderView, and MJRefresh as the refreshing component. And the UITableView's content height is shorter than the display area.(The vertical scroll indicator don't display).

Problem:
When pull down to refresh, there is a vertical indicator flashes from left top to right and gradually getting longer, then disappear.

Demo:https://github.com/hengyizhangcn/UISearchControllerDemo

Comment: Please share some code. It makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks, the demo is uploaded!

Answer (score 0):

Temporary processing, realise the protocol method `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    BOOL result = [self.tableView.mj_header isRefreshing];
    if (result) {
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    } else {
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    }
}
```

If the refreshing component is refreshing, hide the vertical scroll indicator, otherwise show it.